# How to write better this part of code in method

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I write this code

```
public Task<TResponse>  CustomGetMethod<TResponse>(HelperUrl helperUrl,List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> query_string,string ParametersForUrl = "")
        where TResponse : class
    {
        string queryString = string.Empty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParametersForUrl))
            queryString += ParametersForUrl;
        if (query_string != null && query_string.Count > 0)
            queryString += $"?{String.Join("&", query_string.ConvertAll(a => $"{a.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(a.Value)}"))}";
```

do you have idea for get better ?

Comment: "better" in what respect?

Comment: i don`t like write just    if      do you have idea for this ?